# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

In my randomizing script I'm getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById is not a function. I looked at some other issues with this error on stack overflow and tried to fix it. I declared the variable before the function, and because a variable changes every time, I set it to another variable.
I have no idea why this code is an issue, any help is appreciated.
HTML:

```
<div id="GetPlayers">
    <input maxlength="1" id="input"> <button id="gp" onclick="gp()">Start!</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button id="DJ" onclick="DJ();">Display Your Job!</button>
    <br/>
    <span id="DS">1) Input Amount Of Players. 2)Click 'Display Your Job!'</span>
</div>
```

Javscript

```
var al;
var rl;
var bd;
function gp(){
    players = document.getElementById("input").value;
    if(isNaN(players)){
        alert(players.toUpperCase() + "'s Players? Please Fix"); 
        return;
    }
    if(players === " "){
        alert("Please Define How Many People Are Playing!");
        return;
    }
    if(players === ""){
        alert("Please Define How Many People Are Playing!");
        return;
    }
    if(players < 4){
        alert("Sorry, You Need Atleast 4 Players To Play!");
        return;
    }
    SA(players)
}
function SA(players){
    var positions = ["Murderer", "Judge", "Innocent", "Innocent"]; //Pre-set positions
    if(players == 5){
        positions.push("Co-Judge");
    }else if(players == 6){
        positions.push("Innocent", "Co-Judge"); 
    }else if(players == 7){
        positions.push("Murderer-2!", "Innocent", "Co-Judge");
    }
    Randomize(players, positions)
}
function shuffle(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
}
function Randomize(players, positions){
    rl = shuffle(positions);
    al = positions.length;
    confirm("You Have: " + al + " Players, Correct?");
    alert(al + ". " + rl);
}
var counter;
var rl;
var c;
var p;
function DJ(){
    counter = 0;
    var bd = 0;
    for(var c = 0; c < al + 1; c++){
        if(counter == 0){
            p = c;
            document.getElementById("DS").innerHTML=(rl[p]);
            document.getElementById("DJ").innerHTML=("Click To Clear!");
            counter = 1;
            BlankDisplay()
        }
    }
}
function BlankDisplay(){
    if(counter == 1){
        document.getElementById=("Click The Button Above To See Your Job!");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're assigning a string value to `document.getElementById()`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this function:

```
function BlankDisplay(){
    if(counter == 1){
        document.getElementById=("Click The Button Above To See Your Job!");   
    }
}
```

You're redefining `document.getElementById`, to a string.

So, whenever you call `document.getElementById` again, after that, you're trying to execute a string, hence why you get `not a function`. So I guess you want to change that to:

```
function BlankDisplay(){
    if(counter == 1){
        document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML = "Click The Button Above To See Your Job!";   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well your problem is this line:

```
document.getElementById=("Click The Button Above To See Your Job!");
```

It is not selecting an element and setting the text like you do in a bunch of other places, you are setting it to a string.

Comment: By learning the basics of JavaScript.

Comment: IMO, even if the question lacks research, you shouldn't answer it poorly.

Comment: Thanks for your down vote and opinion. The answer should have been obvious once it is pointed out. Looks like tired eye syndrome to me. I did not feel like the question needed a full explanation. I am still surprised this question is open, guess the American holiday has slowed down the close votes.

Comment: As much as you should abstain to put down vote when a user takes time to a correct answer.

Comment: @TyrionGraphiste An incomplete answer can be correct, but still incomplete. Anyway, already removed the down vote since it was improved.